# Issue with modify file size in SQL 2012 and 2014

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to Alter the size of the database

`ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'MyDB', SIZE = 11240000KB )`

This works fine with `2016` version but when I execute the same in `2012` or `2014` it is taking more time (`nearly 30 minutes`) and some times I am getting timeout exception so can some one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This works fine with 2016 version but when I execute the same in 2012 or 2014 it is taking more time (nearly 30 minutes) and some times I am getting timeout exception so can some one help me

SQL Server 2016 [can configure instant file initialisation during installation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2016/03/25/sql-2016-it-just-runs-faster-instant-file-initialization/). It was probably enabled for your 2016 instance. Enable it for your 2012 and 2014 instances, too.

Comment: Is there any possibility to do it by using sql commands after installation

Comment: Thanks I added the following to the mentioned one`NT Service\MSSQLSERVER` and it works